# Unable to screenshot highlighted element in Mozilla, but able to screenshot highlighted element in Chrome

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox

```
`ICapabilities caps = ((RemoteWebDriver)driver).Capabilities;
        string browserName = string.Empty;
        browserName = caps.GetCapability("browserName").ToString();
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        // element to be highlighted
        element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='ctl00_MainContent_txtAdd2']")); 

        js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].style.border='3px solid red'", element);

        Screenshot image = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
        string testMethodName = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name;
        image.SaveAsFile("C:/temp/" + browserName + testMethodName + ".png", ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
```

---

[Screenshot on Highlighted Element in Chrome-Work Fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TesET.png)

[Unable to Screenshot on Highlighted Element in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDzZ9.png)

Is there any particular reason why I am unable to highlighted and screenshot in Firefox but in Chrome it work fine?